# What's the best way to make a game launcher?

Tags: unity, free-to-play, launcher

I am a new game dev, and would like to make a launcher for my games. All my games would be in ONE launcher, and it'd be similar to the Minecraft Launcher. I wanna do it for free too.

The main reason I wanna do it is to update my games. I don't have a file server, so the files would be on Google Drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to be more specific? What exactly would you like to know? Is there any particular problem with creating a game launcher you wonder how to solve?

Comment: @Philipp nah, no problems. And I'd want it so you can get older versions of the games if you want.

Comment: If you don't have any problems, then I suppose there's nothing you need our help with and we can close this question? If not, please edit your question to identify one specific step you need help with.

Comment: I meant what can I use to make one, what's the best design etc

Comment: A launcher is a software. What do you use to make software? - Given that you tag Unity, I'd say, use Visual Studio and C#. And given that you say Google Drive, I'd say, use Google Drive API (any search of "How to download from Google Drive with C#" will point you there). You can find a NuGet for Google Drive API for .NET. *That was not hard to figure out.*

Comment: Theraot, easier *said* than *done.*  DMGregory, I think he's trying to figure out where to start, which is why he hasn't had any problems.

Comment: Millard, yeah that's true